# How to retrieve a single value from a TinyDB database?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tinydb

I'm learning how to use TinyDB on Python and I have the basics working (add, remove, update etc.). But now I'm trying to retrieve specific values from the database. The code I'm using is in this method:

```
def showpassword():
    show = userdb.get(where("username") == txtname.get())
    txtshow.insert(0, show)
```

When I run the method, it displays the output as follows:

```
{'username': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe'}
```

How can I get it so that I can display only the user's name or surname and without any brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyDb stores its data as JSON which is represented in Python as a dictionary.

Change the line

```
txtshow.insert(0, show)
```

to

```
txtshow.insert(0, "{username} {surname}".format(**show)
```

Look [here](https://pyformat.info) for a deeper dive in to string formatting.